# How do I print values only once, instead of each single value?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to make a script that scans an image, and then tells me what color pixels are in it, but when I print the pixels color value, it prints the same color value for every time it occurs in the image.

I have figured out to sort the values sort they are besides each other.

```
from PIL import Image


img = Image.open('images/image.png')

print(img.size)
print("pixels")

pix = img.load()
pix_val = list(img.getdata())

pix_val.sort()

print(pix_val)
```

It prints the color values for each time they occur in the image, so I get a very long print.

Comment: Maybe try using a `set`?

Comment: Could you maybe use an example? :)

Comment: `pix_val = set(list(img.getdata())`. See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: it didn't help?

Comment: What is the output when you call `print(pix_val)`

Comment: There are easier ways of doing this. What do you plan to do next in your processing?

Comment: Added an answer below as there was too much to discuss in a comment. You are still going to get loads of output as there are many unique pixels in a 1920x1080 image but utilizing `set` will extract all the **unique** configurations present.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the distribution of unique pixels using the following code:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(pix_val)
```

If you only need to know which are the unique colours, just run the following code as Adrian told you on the comments.

```
set(pix_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) will remove the duplicate pixels as they collide when they are hashed into the set. Using the following script on a test image I have on my machine:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('sample.png')
print('Image size:    {}'.format(img.size))

pix = img.load()
pix_val = list(img.getdata())

pix_val.sort()

print('Total pixels:  {}'.format(len(pix_val)))
print('Unique pixels: {}'.format(len(set(pix_val))))
```

I get the following output:

```py
Image size:    (1920, 1080)
Total pixels:  2073600
Unique pixels: 5894
```

The output of the raw data prints the set of all RGBA configurations present in the image. You will also notice the significant decrease RGBA configurations as there are now 5894 **unique** pixel configurations present in the image from the total of 2,073,600 **total** pixels.

Just for reference, here is sample output when calling `print(pix_val)`:

```
[(0, 0, 0, 255), 
(0, 0, 0, 255), 
(0, 0, 0, 255), 
(0, 0, 0, 255), 
(0, 0, 0, 255), 
... continued ... ]
```

And here is the sample output from `print(set(pix_val))`:

```
{(123, 86, 90, 255), 
(142, 200, 76, 255), 
(247, 243, 248, 255), 
(130, 190, 119, 255), 
(181, 231, 231, 255), 
(229, 243, 191, 255),
... continued ... }
```

I would also like to add that because a set is unordered, if you would like to iterate through the set of unique pixels you have just extracted, you will need to use one of the methods described [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-set-in-python/). Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad this worked for you, please consider accepting this solution if it helped resolve your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the unique colours in an image like this.

Starting image (`blocks.png`):

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

# Open image and ensure RGB
im = Image.open('blocks.png').convert('RGB')

# Make into Numpy array
n = np.array(im)

# Reshape into a tall column of pixels, each with 3 RGB pixels and get unique rows (colours)
colours  = np.unique(n.reshape(-1,3), axis=0)

print(colours)
```

**Output**

```
[[  0   0   0]
 [  0   0 255]
 [  0 255   0]
 [  0 255 255]
 [126 126 126]
 [255   0   0]
 [255   0 255]
 [255 255   0]
 [255 255 255]]
```

If you want the **number** of unique colours, just append:

```
Ncolours = len(colours)
```