# Finding count of unique triple in Numpy Ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, unique

I have some image in ndarray form like this:

```
# **INPUT**
img = np.array(
[
    [
        [0, 0, 255],
        [0, 0, 255],
        [0, 0, 255],
        [0, 0, 255],
        [0, 0, 255],
        [0, 0, 255],
        [0, 0, 255],
        [0, 0, 255]
    ],
    [
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [0, 255, 0],
        [0, 255, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [255, 0, 0],
        [0, 255, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0]
    ],
    [
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0],
        [255, 0, 0]
    ],
])
```

I need to find count of each color in my image,i.e. count of 3 following tuples: **[0, 0, 255],[255, 0, 0],[0, 255, 0]**. In this case:

```
# **Desired OUTPUT**
 unique  [[  0   0 255]
 [255   0   0]
 [  0 255   0]]
 counts  [8 21 3]
```

this is what I have done:

```
print('AXIS 0 -----------------------------------')
unique0, counts0 = np.unique(img, axis=0, return_counts=True)
print('unique0 ', unique0)
print('counts0 ', counts0)
```

This is the output:

```
  AXIS 0 -----------------------------------
  unique0  [[[  0   0 255]
  [  0   0 255]
  [  0   0 255]
  [  0   0 255]
  [  0   0 255]
  [  0   0 255]
  [  0   0 255]
  [  0   0 255]]

 [[255   0   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]]

 [[255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]]

 [[255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [255   0   0]]]
counts0  [1 1 1 1]
```

I get similar result when trying with `axis=1` (counts1  [2 1 5]).

I have also tried giving a tuple as axis input, `axis=(0, 1)`, which return the error `TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/57571670/2836621

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by using [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to concatenate the ndarray along the first axis, and *then* use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) as you where doing, setting `return_counts=True`, which will return the counts of the flattened `2D`  array:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(np.concatenate(mg), axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

---

```
print(unique)
[[  0   0 255]
 [  0 255   0]
 [255   0   0]]

print(counts)
# array([ 8,  3, 21], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
elements, counts = np.unique(img.reshape((-1, 3)), axis=0, return_counts=True)
print(elements, counts)
```

**Output**

```
[[  0   0 255]
 [  0 255   0]
 [255   0   0]] [ 8  3 21]
```